# Why does my VF page display an error instead of my LWC?

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app

I have a custom action button on Salesforce Maps that when clicked opens a VF page that contains an LWC. Upon rendering the page is says "You can't view this page, either because you don't have permission or because the page isn't supported on mobile devices."

I have done some research on this and found nothing that solves the issue. I have also enabled the VF page to be available for mobile apps. The page can only be reached by clicking the button within Salesforce Maps.

If anyone has an thoughts or action that could solve the issue, I'd really appreciate the help.

Thanks,
Kev

Comment: Does your Visualforce use an Apex controller, or maybe the component is using an Apex controller? The user should have access to those classes, if they exist.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer for why this error appears, but the workaround is to use the Salesforce1 app and add the Salesforce Maps to the navigation using it within Salesforce1, instead of using the two separated apps.